# Updating integers in a FormulateForm doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, vue-formulate

I'm just getting started looking at Vue Formulate, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.  I'm binding a `FormulateForm` to a simple object that contains a few properties.  When I initially set the model, the values display properly in the form, but when I set the model to a different object, the text and boolean properties are updated in the form, but the integer properties retain their original values.  Seems odd that something so basic would be broken, so am I doing something wrong?

```
<template>
  <div>
    person_id: {{localData.person_id}}
    <FormulateForm v-model="localData">
      <FormulateInput name="person_id" label="Person Id" />
      <FormulateInput name="first_name" label="First Name" />
      <FormulateInput name="age" label="Age" />
      <FormulateInput name="is_cool" type="checkbox" label="Cool?" />
    </FormulateForm>
    <p>
      Click setData1 and then setData2.  The integer values (person_id and age) are not updated in the form.
    </p>
    <div style="display: flex">
      <FormulateInput type="button" label="setData1" @click="setData1" />
      <FormulateInput type="button" label="setData2" @click="setData2" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    localData: {}    
  }),
  methods: {
    setData1: function(){
      this.localData = { person_id: 1, first_name: 'Bob', age: 24, is_cool: true };
    },
    setData2: function(){
      this.localData = { person_id: 2, first_name: 'Tony', age: 32, is_cool: false };
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-formulate-integers-dont-update-vvghs)

Comment: I tested changing person_id: 1 and person_id: 2 in your code to string  person_id: '1', person_id: '2' and it started working. I'm not familiar with FormulateForm, there must be  something to add for it to start working with Number. Also, be careful using the assign "=" operator with objects. It can mess the Vue reactivity. use Object.assign instead as shown here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: It actually doesn't even matter if there's a `FormulateInput` for the number property (I just added it in the example for clarity).  The underlying property doesn't update regardless.

Comment: Numbers are not valid values for text inputs, switch those to strings and you're good to go.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem (and I don't want to have to cast all my numbers to text; this library is supposed to *reduce* the hassle of creating forms).  Things work correctly if the FormulateInputs aren't wrapped in a FormulateForm (which is how I've worked around this).  It seems like a bug with FormulateForm.

Comment: @Jerrad if you've found a legit bug please file an issue!

Answer (score 1):

Just add options to checkbox as below

```
 <FormulateInput name="is_cool" type="checkbox" label="Cool?" :options="is_cool"/>
```